# Docker Swarm Secrets + Portainer

Tags: docker-swarm, node-red, portainer

I run my Node-Red on Docker Swarm + Portainer.
I want to define several credentials, e.g some for development, some for test and some for production, so that I can create 3 containers, one for each environment and use the relevant credentials for each of them.
I'm a bit confused regarding the right way to choose - From what I understand, I can use Docker Swarm Secrets, but then I don't know how to access them from the Node-Red editor; or I can use the "credentialsSecret" in settings.js - but I'm not sure if it's suitable for multiple credentials.

Can someone assist?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear from the question what exactly you are asking here. `credentialsSecret` is a key to encrypt actual service credentials used by the flow, not a way to pass service credentials to Node-RED. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63243095/edit) the question to give a lot more detail about exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the credentials are passed into the containers as Environment Variables then they can be included in the nodes configuration as follows:

> Any node property can be set with an environment variable by setting
> its value to a string of the form `${ENV_VAR}`. When the runtime loads
> the flows, it will substitute the value of that environment variable
> before passing it to the node.
>
> This only works if it replaces the entire property - it cannot be used
> to substitute just part of the value. For example, it is not possible
> to use `CLIENT-${HOST}`.

E.g. if you have a environment variable called `MQTT_PASSWORD`, that holds the password to use when connecting to your MQTT broker, you would enter `${MQTT_PASSWORD}` into the password field for the MQTT broker config node.

This will be populated when the Node-RED runtime loads the flow.

You can read more in the Node-RED documentation [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply.
My question is different - I'm not setting up the credentials as env variables. When I use Docker Swarm Secrets, the credentials are not accessible as env variables, so my question is how can I access them that way?
Or is it better to use the credentialSecret in settings.js? If so, how can I save multiple credentials and access them?

Comment: If they are not environment variables then you can't

Comment: It looks like Docker Swarm mounts files into the container with the Secrets, you would have to read this and then generate a valid `flow_cred.json` that was in the right format and then encrypted with the `credentialSecret` from the `settings.js` file. This is a none trivial task

Comment: Thanks, I know it isn't. That's why I ask for your help :) I couldn't find a guide online how to do it. Can someone help?